How do I disable touchpad coasting?
Pretty self-explanatory, my laptop is a bit laggy, which makes touchpad scroll coasting unbearable. I'm a bit new to Ubuntu, so I apologize if this is a dumb question. Thanks in advance!

What do you mean by touchpad coasting? Can you please add more details?

When you scroll with a touchpad and let go, it "coasts" - scrolls a bit further, despite no contact / interaction

Please [edit] your question and explain this. As you can see, it is quite far from self explanatory :) Please also make sure to mention exactly which flavor and version of Ubuntu you are using and what your hardware is.
